# Downloading data from Sentinel's API - LTA error

Tags: python, remote-sensing, sentinel-1, sentinelsat

I am trying to download data and I get this error when I am using the `sentinelsat` Python API:

```
sentinelsat.sentinel.SentinelAPILTAError: HTTP status 500 Internal Server Error: Trying to download an offline product
Product 93351dbb-46fe-4faf-b35d-aa7fba801ff2 is not online. Triggering retrieval from long term archive.
Trying to download an offline product
There was an error retrieving 93351dbb-46fe-4faf-b35d-aa7fba801ff2 from the LTA
```

Does this mean the data will be available within 24hrs since I have triggered the retrieval or does the error mean it didn’t work?

Answer (score 1):

Some archives data from ESA Sentinel hub is not always ready to download (called offline product), that's why you got such error messages. From API, I am not sure but from gui, you can handle it.

Answer (score 1):

The new Sentinelsat v0.14 has been just been released with some bug fixes and esp. improved handling of Long-Term Archive (LTA) data search and download. It is available from here:

https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat/releases/tag/v0.14